# What's Multidimensional Baby's tears effect?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth

I've just tried my first run with the new DLC of *Binding of Isaac: Afterbirth*, and I've found several new items.

One of them is this Devil item:

[image: Multidimensional Baby]

It's called **Multidimensional Baby** and it costs 1 heart container.
It's a *familiar* that follows Isaac and it rarely shoots a new kind of tear.
I say "rarely" because it doesn't shoot with the frequency as my other familiar (*Little Steven*).

It's a blinking black/white tear, what's its effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Multidimensional Baby item is described in this video:

As shown in the video, the Multidimensional Baby familiar doubles the projectiles you and your other helpers fire, along with giving them the flashing black and white effect. Contrary to what's said in the video, you don't necessarily need to be in contact with the familiar to make this effect work. While that's one way to get the effect, any projectiles that pass through the familiar will also gain this effect. The Multidimensional Baby will follow your movements, but with a delay of a few seconds, making it difficult to use if you need to move around a lot.

Other than doubling the number of projectiles you fire, it doesn't add any special effects onto them.

Comment: Thank you! I've just found the same video but your answer is surely correct. In my run I didn't notice the doubling effect, because my *Little Steven*'s purple tear always covered the second flashing tear, and I had laser tears so it was hard to understand how the new familiar actually works.

Comment: Regarding your last edit, I can confirm that you can also shoot through the familiar to double the projectile.

Answer (score 4):

According to [PlatinumGod](http://platinumgod.co.uk/afterbirth):

> **Multidimensional Baby** is a familiar baby that will follow your movement pattern on a 3 second delay. Tears that pass through the baby will double up and increase in damage while flashing black & white.

Answer (score 2):

From my observation this familiar doesn't shoot on its own. Instead it converts any Isaac's tear passing its body to 2 black/white tears.

Didn't found those tears any special though.

Comment: Oh, this explains a lot. If nobody finds further info I'll accept your answer.